# php - Enabling users to favorite posts

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, database

On my website I want to allow users to favorite posts. A logged in user is directed to a page which shows all the posts and under each one I placed a hyperlink to favorite. I want the text to change from favorite to favorited and the other way around. How do I do that?

**HTML and PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connection.php');

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_favorite = "SELECT username, post_id FROM favorite";
$favorite = mysql_query($query_favorite, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_favorite = mysql_fetch_assoc($favorite);
$totalRows_favorite = mysql_num_rows($favorite);
?>

<a href="#" class="favourite">Favourite</a>
```

**Tables in my datatbase**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `profilepic` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dato` date NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `text` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `favorite` (
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`post_id`),
  KEY `fk_favorite_post1_idx` (`post_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_favorite_user` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `user` (`username`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_favorite_post1` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`post_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connection.php');

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_favorite = "SELECT username, post_id FROM favorite";
$favorite = mysql_query($query_favorite, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_favorite = mysql_fetch_assoc($favorite);
$totalRows_favorite = mysql_num_rows($favorite);

if(in_array($_POST['id'], $row_favorite))
{
   //is already favourited, run a query to remove that row from the db, so it won't be favorited anymore

}
else
{
   //post is not favourited already, run a query to add a new favourite to the db.
}

?>
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="favourite" data-id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">Favourite</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.favourite').on('click', null, function() {
        var _this = $(this);
        var post_id = _this.data('id');
        $.ajax({
          type     : 'POST',
          url      : '/file.php',
          dataType : 'json',
          data     : 'id='+ post_id,
          complete : function(data) {
               if(_this.siblings('.typcn-star-outline'))
               {
                 _this.html('<span class="typcn typcn-star-full-outline"></span>Favourite');
               }
               else
               {
                 _this.html('<span class="typcn typcn-star-outline"></span>Favourited');
               }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also, please note that in PHP mysql_* functions have been deprecated and are unsafe to use (they allow for SQL Injection attacks). Learn more about PDO here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: thanks! I didn't mention that, but I use typicons so that there is a star (full for favorited posts and outlined for not favorited) next to the 'Favourite' text - `<a href="#" class="favourite"><span class="typcn typcn-star-full-outline"></span>Favourite</a>` or `<a href="#" class="favourite"><span class="typcn typcn-star-outline"></span>Favourite</a>`. would that mean big complications if I wanted to include that? if not, could you edit your answer? :) i'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I've edited my answer. Play around with the if statement a bit. I'm not quite sure which typicon means which. But, that will be a good start. Don't forget to accept my answer if you are satisfied :).

Comment: thank you! I also wonder if this code sends the data about a favorited post to my database?

Comment: also, the first code (without typicons) worked ok, but the new one only favorites without enabling 'unfavoriting'. why is that?

Comment: Try changing the typcn-star-outline and typcn-star-full-outline around inside the jQuery if statement. I've updated your code above to get you started with the PHP. You'll need to add a data-id attribute to the anchor tag so when you use AJAX to send to PHP, PHP will know which post you want to favourite.

Comment: @LeeSalminen am looking for `PDO tutorial` is there any tutorial online ?, i tried a lot and couldn't find anyone.