# Same ID inserted in Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a tour website where multiple destinations are appearing. Users can add his/her favorite destination. The issue is While adding the favorites destination, the First time it works fine but next time adding to favorites the same destination ID enters into the database. The like expression changes only the first time. Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
foreach ($listing_data as $list) {
    $like = FALSE;
    foreach ($favorites as $fav) {
        if ($fav['link_id'] == $list['id']) {
            $like = TRUE;
        }
    }
    if ($like) {
        ?>
        <li class="pull-right"><a class="Theme" id="like_done"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> </a></li>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="" class="Theme1" id="<?= $list['id']; ?>"><i class="far fa-heart"></i> </a></li>
        <input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="<?php echo $data['is_user_login'][0]['id']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="listing_id" value="<?php echo $list['id']; ?>">
    <?php }
}
?>
```

**And Here is my Jquery Code

```
    $('.Theme1').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        my_favorite();
    });
    
    function my_favorite() {
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        var listing_id = $('#listing_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: BASE_URL + 'user/my_favorites',
            type: 'post',
            data: {u_id: user_id, l_id: listing_id},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.status == 'success') {
                    $('#' + listing_id).children("i").attr("class", "fas fa-heart");
                } else {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: what will happens `if next time adding to favorites the same destination ID`???

Comment: Your `id`s don't appear to be unique. `user_id` is probably fine because the same user is logged in. Although technically that also is wrong. Every `id` should only occur once.

Comment: @KUMAR exactly, the same ID insert into DB and like expression not changed.

Comment: @user3783243 so what is the way to make this Unique?

Comment: The answer is available on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277879/how-to-add-item-post-to-favourites)