# Unable to create SQL table for favourites system, ERROR Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

Am trying to create `Add to favorites` system in pdo so initially i started to create `database` with help of this question

[php - Enabling users to favorite posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583300/php-enabling-users-to-favorite-posts)  as guide.

and try to run

```
CREATE TABLE `favorite` (
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`id`),
  KEY `id10067859_sell` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `id10067859_sell` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `members` (`username`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `id10067859_sell` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `allpostdata` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

in my `myphpadmin` and MySQL said `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint`

can someone explain me whats wrong with my database.

Here are the other `database` code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `allpostdata` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mca` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sca` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tit` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fue` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `product_brand` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mdl` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `prd` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `drv` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `prs` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `des` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cno` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lcn` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pdt` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `vie` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sts` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `une` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `im1` varchar(600) DEFAULT '',
  `im2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `im3` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `im4` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `memberID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `resetToken` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resetComplete` varchar(3) DEFAULT 'No',
  PRIMARY KEY (`memberID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You are using different charsets for your `members`and `favorite`tables. For using foreign key constraint, you need to use the same charset and collate for the columns in the foreign key

Comment: @nacho tried `ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;` for all table still getting same error.

Comment: You have more problems, when you use a foreign key, it needs to have the same data type in boyh tables, in members you have `username` varchar(255) and in favorite `username` varchar(45), the same for id (one is char and the other one is int)